# OpenMP parallel on one machine but serial on another

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I finally got a section of my code to run in parallel with OpenMP without errors. When I deployed the dll to another machine, however, it no longer ran in parallel.

Logging reveals that `omp_in_parallel() == 0` on the other machine but not on mine.

My machine is using an Intel i5 CPU which has 2 hyperthreaded cores for an effective `omp_get_numProcs() == 4`. The other is a virtual machine with 2 processors assigned to it on Microsoft Server 2008, thus `omp_get_numProcs() == 2`.

Are there known settings which would make a program run in parallel under certain values and not others?

Comment: Document the differences between the target machine and yours.  Especially whether the CPU has multiple cores or is hyperthreaded.

Comment: How do you know it's not running in parallel?  Is OMP_NUM_THREADS set properly on the new machine?

Comment: have you tried `omp_get_num_threads()` on the two machines ?  Have you checked the values of the usual environment variables on both machines as Jonathan suggested ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had enabled OpenMp in Debug mode but not in Release. The deployed dll was in Release mode while I was testing it on my machine in Debug configuration.

You'd think I would have learned after the last time this happened. :-)

Thank you for your answers and my apologies for wasting your time.